# Batch Scripting: Forloop and output each iteration

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, cmd

What I wanna do is run tracert 10 times against the same target and extract the results.

the usual command is that I type

```
tracert www.google.se > output.txt
```

but when I try the script below I just get target not found...

```
@echo off
for /l %%x in (1, 1, 10) do (
    echo %%x
     tracert.exe %1% > trc_%1%_%%x.txt 
)
```

anyone with this expertise?

Answer (score 2):

Solved it!

```
@echo off


for /l %%x in (1, 1, 10) do (
    echo trc_%1_%%x.txt
    echo %1
    tracert.exe %1 > trc_%1_%%x.txt

)
```